# XML Parsing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse an XML which looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <WM_Login_MobileAppResponse xmlns="A.MobileAppService">
        <WM_Login_MobileAppResult>
            <Login xmlns="">
                <Customer_Type>5</Customer_Type>
                <Token>token</Token>
            </Login>
        </WM_Login_MobileAppResult>
    </WM_Login_MobileAppResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

I have tried NSXMLParsesr to parse the document. The code I am using is:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"WM_Login_MobileAppResult"]) {
    _resultDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

[_resultDict setObject:_currentString forKey:elementName];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"WM_Login_MobileAppResult"]) {
    [_array addObject:_resultDict];
    _resultDict = nil;
}
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
_currentString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];
}
```

This is the result I am getting:

```
(
    {
    "Customer_Type" = 4;
    Login = "token";
    Token = "token";
    "WM_Login_MobileAppResult" = "token";
}
)
```

Can someone please help me get the proper response?

Comment: What are you expecting to get for `Login` and `WM_Login_MobileAppResult` for the xml string you posted?

Comment: What you expect to get actually?

Comment: I am expecting to store values for only 'Token' and 'Customey_Type'.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change "WM_Login_MobileAppResult"   to   "Login"